# How start process only after connection on Supervisor

Tags: supervisord

How can I make Supervisor wait for the Internet connection to go up before trying to start a process? If the process is running on a wifi dependent server it may fail if the connection is not yet established.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas.Not very good.

1. You can write a wifi monitor program, which is monitored by supervisod too. When your wifi monitor program detects that connection is available, it will call the supervisorctl to actually start your true process.
2. Write a [Event listener](http://supervisord.org/events.html). When wifi is available, your wifi monitor exit with SUCCESS_CODE(0). Your Event listener receives the notification that your wifi monitor has exited successfully. And you event listener will start your process.